# Run BCP without SQL Client

Tags: azure, ms-access, bcp

I had a Access database, since the database limit is 2 GB, I am planning to migrate to Azure Database. I need to upload data with the help of BCP but I was wondering how users will be able to use it since they wont have SSMS installed in their PC. Please help

Comment: Access does provide it's own way of upgrading to a SQL server. Have you tried that?

Comment: @krishKM - Access' built-in SQL Server "upsizing wizard" was removed from Access 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

[SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) v7.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2017/02/21/released-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-v7-3/)

or perhaps the new (still in preview):

[SQL Operations Studio](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/11/15/announcing-sql-operations-studio-for-preview/)

Comment: I got the solution. If you do not have sql client installed in your system but want to run BCP, there are 2 softwares need to be installed

1) Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server®
2) MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi

thanks for the help @Gustav